# Get Logged on Users from a List of Computer Names

Tags: windows, arrays, powershell

I wanted to extract a list of users logged on to remote pc, the ps names would be fed in using a .csv file.

I was able to get a command

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_LoggedOnUser -ComputerName $Computer | Select Antecedent -Unique
```

to query the user names, could any one help me more on how to write this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the csv file contains a ComputerName header:

```
Import-Csv computers.csv | Foreach-Object{
    Get-WmiObject Win32_LoggedOnUser -ComputerName $_.ComputerName | Select-Object __SERVER,Antecedent -Unique | Foreach-Object {
     $domain,$user = [regex]::matches($_.Antecedent,'="([^"]+)"') | Foreach-Object {$_.Groups[1].Value}
     $_ | Select-Object __SERVER,@{Name='Domain';Expression={$domain}},@{Name='User';Expression={$user}}
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Shay levy can you please help me with the following question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6620309/get-the-servernames-where-a-users-session-is-disconnected