# get list of logged on users on remote windows computer from a list computer

Tags: windows, powershell

Wuld have used the old question if I were allowed to ask a follow up question:

My question is the same as here: [Get Logged on Users from a List of Computer Names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6607731/get-logged-on-users-from-a-list-of-computer-names) the answer is good but I dont know how the input computers.csv should be formatted.

Comment: had just missed: set-executionpolicy remotesigned. But I would like to have the result in a .csv file.

Comment: Also exclide local users would be make it look nicer sins these always are system accounts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It (csv file) should be formatted as follows:

```
computername
server1
server2
server3
```

'Computername' is the column name. This can be derived from the code snippet as the Foreach-Object refers to the ComputerName property.

Comment: Yes ("ComputerName" if case sensitive) this was part of it but set-executionpolicy remotesigned was the important part I missed. It now works but I am only able to get the result on screen or .txt if i >> to a file, if I do this I cant manipulate the data as easy sin there is extra line brakes etc.
If I could remove all local users and only show domain users it would be grate.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function Get-MyLoggedOnUsers
{
  param([Array]$Computer)
  Get-WmiObject Win32_LoggedOnUser -ComputerName $Computer |
  Select __SERVER, Antecedent -Unique |
  %{"{0} : {1}\{2}" -f $_.__SERVER, $_.Antecedent.ToString().Split('"')[1],       $_.Antecedent.ToString().Split('"')[3]}
}

$Computers = gc C:\Temp\Computers.txt

Get-MyLoggedOnUsers $Computers
```

-or-

I found this one and modified it to my needs

```
<#
.Synopsis
Queries a computer to check for interactive sessions

.DESCRIPTION
This script takes the output from the quser program and parses this to PowerShell objects

.NOTES   
Name: Get-LoggedOnUser
Author: Jaap Brasser
Version: 1.1
DateUpdated: 2013-06-26

.LINK
http://www.jaapbrasser.com

.PARAMETER ComputerName
The string or array of string for which a query will be executed

.EXAMPLE
.\Get-LoggedOnUser.ps1 -ComputerName server01,server02

Description:
Will display the session information on server01 and server02

.EXAMPLE
'server01','server02' | .\Get-LoggedOnUser.ps1

Description:
Will display the session information on server01 and server02
#>
param(
[CmdletBinding()] 
[Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true,
           ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
[array[]]$ComputerName = (gc C:\Temp\TSRA.txt)
)

process {
foreach ($Computer in $ComputerName) {
    quser /server:$Computer | Select-Object -Skip 1 | ForEach-Object {
        $CurrentLine = $_.Trim() -Replace '\s+',' ' -Split '\s'
        $HashProps = @{
            UserName = $CurrentLine[0]
            ComputerName = $Computer
        }

        # If session is disconnected different fields will be selected
        if ($CurrentLine[2] -eq 'Disc') {
                $HashProps.SessionName = $null
                $HashProps.Id = $CurrentLine[1]
                $HashProps.State = $CurrentLine[2]
                $HashProps.IdleTime = $CurrentLine[3]
                $HashProps.LogonTime = $CurrentLine[4..6] -join ' '
        } else {
                $HashProps.SessionName = $CurrentLine[1]
                $HashProps.Id = $CurrentLine[2]
                $HashProps.State = $CurrentLine[3]
                $HashProps.IdleTime = $CurrentLine[4]
                $HashProps.LogonTime = $CurrentLine[5..7] -join ' '
        }

        New-Object -TypeName PSCustomObject -Property $HashProps |
        Select-Object -Property UserName,ComputerName,SessionName,Id,State,IdleTime,LogonTime
    } | Out-GridView -Title "Users Logged in $Computer"

   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OK... I know this question is an older one but I recently ran into this exact quandary where I had to pull all the users from a specific domain that had logged in to all the WORKSTATIONS on that domain. Here is what I came up with from a snippet of code that I found and modified fairly extensively. The script reads the list of workstations from a Workstation.CSV file and outputs to a nicely formatted .csv file that can be opened with excel.

```html
#
# ########################################################################################
# Script Execution is as follows
# .\LoggedOn_All.ps1
# ########################################################################################
# Script generates a list ofComputers from Active Directory and
# pulls listing of all users that have logged in to those Workstations
# Before running script, rename or delete the following files
# Workstations.csv
# Worksation_Logged_On_Users.csv
# NotPingable.csv
##########################################################################################

#Generate a listing of Workstations from Active Directory
#While this command can be run inside the script, I comment it out and copy it to powershell
#so that I can verify the contents of the file before running the script
Get-ADComputer -Filter * -SearchBase "<DISTINGUISHED NAME of the OU that contains your Workstations>" | Select -Exp Name >> Workstations.csv

#Set workstation list file (get list of workstations from file)
$list = Get-Content "<put full path here> Workstations.csv"

#Set Output file
$OUTPUT = "<put full path here> Worksation_Logged_On_Users.csv"
#set headers in CSV output file
echo "Workstation Name,User,LogonTime" | Out-File -Encoding ascii -FilePath $OUTPUT

#begin script logic
$list | ForEach-Object {

echo "Current computer $_"

#Test if system is online
Invoke-Expression "ping -n 1 -w 500 $_" | Out-Null
$ping = $LASTEXITCODE

#If Pingable perform the following collection actions
if (!$ping){

#Retrieve listings of ALL users that have logged on to the Workstation/Laptop and send results to Output File

$NetLogs = Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkLoginProfile -ComputerName $_
foreach ($NetLog in $NetLogs) {
 
if ($NetLog.Name -match "<DOMAIN>*" -AND $NetLog.LastLogon -match "(\d{14})") { 
$row = "" | Select Name,LogonTime 
$row.Name = $NetLog.Name 
$row.LogonTime=[datetime]::ParseExact($matches[0], "yyyyMMddHHmmss", $null) 
    foreach ($RName in $row) {
        $USR = $row.Name
        $LTime = $row.LogonTime
        #Write "Workstation Name, User, and TimeStamp" results to Output File
        echo "$_,$USR,$LTime" >> $OUTPUT }
} 
} 

} else {
#If System is not pingable, the System Name is written to the NotPingable.csv file
echo "$_ not pingable"
echo "$_" >> NotPingable.csv
}

}
```